# "No resource found that matches the given name..:" - Android Studio 2.1.2 (React Native App)

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-studio-2.1

after developing the react native app for ios I wanted to also test it on android.

After following the steps from the docs and setting up Android Studio to test I sadly can't run the app because of the following errors to which I don't seem to find the proper solution. Even though similar questions have been asked before.

The errors:

```
Error:(6, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [ios_ver] /path/ios_ver/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(6, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [ios_ver] /path/ios_ver/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
Error:(6, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [ios_ver] /path/ios_ver/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
Error:(11, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [ios_ver] /path/ios_ver/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
```

I asked an Android Dev. Friend of mine, but he only said that he never needed to edit the manifest file nor had a similar problem.

My Manifest File:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:debuggable="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ios_ver"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-mail')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'libs'
}
```

I'll gladly hear any kind of solution from you. 
Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

Module Settings

[image]

When I click the + to add a Library then the following window pops up:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't see any list of libraries from which i could choose appcompat-v7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to simulate this react native android app.

While you can run your react native IOS App directly from Xcode,
it seems that it doesn't work if you run your react native Android App directly from the Android Studio.

You **must** run it through the command *react-native run-android* as stated in the docs

Answer (score 4):

**Fix for React Native App:**

You must ***run*** it through the command *react-native run-android* as stated in the official docs.

**Fix if you are not using React Native:**

Your `Android Manifest` file is missing some things that are required to run your app. Most of these are under the `<application` `</application>` tags. Here is an example below which you can use to fix yours:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.prad.myapplication">

     <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:supportsRtl="true"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
         <activity
             android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
    </application>
 </manifest>
```

After comparing you manifest with the one above, try the following below:

**Check string resources:**

*Path:* `res/values/strings.xml`

```
<string name="app_name">"MyFirstApp"</string>
```

**Check style resources:**

*Path:* `res/values/styles`

Change **The.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar** to **Theme.Light**

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**Check build.gradle**

Change `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"` to `buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
}
```

**Something else to debug this issue:**

*Right click* on your app

Open *Module Settings*

Select *Dependencies* tab

Click on green *+* symbol which is on the right side

Select *Library Dependency*

[image]

Choose *appcompat-v7* from list

[image]

Comment: Some things that you have written under activity are under application in my code. Does that matter? I have tried out your code and replaced the entries with mine and I still get the same error :/

Comment: Sure. Updated my question! Also my res/values/strings.xml is defined as shown in your answer :)

Comment: thanks or the updated answer, unfortunately i still receive the same error

Comment: Could you post your build.gradle file?
Let's take a look in there as well.

Comment: Updated my question with the build.gradle file :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have updated my question again.